# Getting DbContext when resolving a singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Within `ConfigureServices` I have

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

as well as

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyModel>(s =>
{
    var dbContext = s.GetService<MyContext>();
    var lastItem= dbContext.Items.LastOrDefault();
    return new MyModel(lastItem);
});
```

But `s.GetService<MyContext>()` throws an error:

Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyContext' from root provider.

How can I achieve that? I don't want to inject `MyDbContext` in `MyModel` contructor as it is in a library which should have no reason to know about `Entity Framework`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AddDbContext` defaults to using a [*scoped*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#scoped) lifestyle:

> Scoped lifetime services ([AddScoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped)) are created once per client request (connection).

The reason an error is being thrown is that you're attempting to obtain an instance of `MyContext` from outside of a request. As the error message suggests, it is not possible to obtain a *scoped* service from the root `IServiceProvider`.

For your purposes, you can create a scope explicitly and use that for your dependency resolution, like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyModel>(sp =>
{
    using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();
        var lastItem = dbContext.Items.LastOrDefault();
        return new MyModel(lastItem);
    }
});
```

This code above creates a *scoped* `IServiceProvider` that can be used for obtaining *scoped* services.

Comment: The line with `new MyModel(lastItem)` will only be called once when the server starts correct? So lastItem is loaded from the database when the server starts and will never change when during the server runtime new items are added to the DB

Comment: @SimonHeinen Yeah, that's right. *Technically*, it'll happen when `IMyModel` is first requested, but it will be just the once and it won't change, as you've stated.